# C# Bad Word Space Filter

Tags: c#, filter

I try bad word filter, but its failing if someone write like "f u c k" so i try filter out all spaces but then put back spaces correct. Here's an image to illustrate:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/353eee9.png]

I hope you understand! :) And if you dont understand me please dont give me "-1"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static List<string> list_0;
    private static List<string> list_1;
    private static List<bool> list_2;
    private static List<string> list_3;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list_0 = new List<string>();
        list_1 = new List<string>();
        list_2 = new List<bool>();
        list_3 = new List<string>();
        list_0.Add("fuck");
        list_1.Add("****");
        list_2.Add(true);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Message = textBox2.Text;

        if (list_0 != null && list_0.Count > 0)
        {
            int num = -1;
            foreach (string current in list_0)
            {
                textBox3.Text = FilterSpace(Message.ToLower());
                num++;
                if (FilterSpace(Message.ToLower()).Contains(current.ToLower()) && list_2[num])
                {
                    Message = Regex.Replace(FilterSpace(Message.ToLower()), current, list_1[num], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (FilterSpace(Message.ToLower()).Contains(" " + current.ToLower() + " "))
                    {
                        Message = Regex.Replace(Message, current, list_1[num], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    }
                }
                textBox1.Text = Message;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string FilterSpace(string message)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = message[i];
            if (c == ' ')
                sb.Append("");
            else
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "failing" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Why can't you just add the "word": "f u c k" to your bad-words-list?

Comment: They can do like "f   (big space)                   u c k" :/ so its not stop them

Comment: Simply stripping spaces might not be a good idea as you risk your bad word filter get too agressive. For example, sentence "Be As Silly As You Can" would be transformed into "Be ***illy As You Can"

Comment: Put another way, someone will always find a way to circumvent your filter.  `f@u@c@k` or `fûck`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to handle this, asking the .NET Regex object to replace matching strings in the input string.

You need to carefully construct the pattern though, to handle the spaces.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] badWords = new[] { "bad", "word", "words" };

    string input = "This is a bad string containing some of the words in the"
        + " list, even one w o r d that has whitespace";
    string output = Filter(input, badWords);
    Debug.WriteLine(output);
}

public static string Filter(string input, string[] badWords)
{
    var re = new Regex(
        @"\b("
        + string.Join("|", badWords.Select(word =>
            string.Join(@"\s*", word.ToCharArray())))
        + @")\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return re.Replace(input, match =>
    {
        return new string('*', match.Length);
    });
}
```

Basically, I construct the regular expression like this:

```
\b(              <-- start at a word boundary and start a capture group
b\s*a\s*d        <-- the word "bad" with an optional amount of whitespace
|                <-- next word
w\s*o\s*r\s*d    <-- the word "word" with an optional amount of whitespace
|                <-- next word
... and so on
)\b              <-- end the capture group, and end at a word boundary
```

I then ask the evaluator delegate to replace each string with the appropriate amount of stars.

Final output:

> `This is a *** string containing some of the ***** in the list, even one ******* that has whitespace`

Comment: Yes, it does, see the example, the "w o r d" in there is replaced with `*******`.

Comment: If message is like "f (long space) u c k" it works? And i need extra extanssion or program idk?

Comment: If you want it to handle parts of words, without having to add all variations of a word, remove the two `\b` elements in the pattern.

Comment: Can't you try it and see for yourself? You can test it here: http://ideone.com/cuKwyk

Comment: First, +1 for the great answer. Second, remove ` output.Dump();` as it is look as a method extension which is missing in your code.

Comment: I did say it was a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example, didn't I? But I can replace it with Debug.WriteLine.

Comment: You did but please agree with me that we have to be general as possible when answering general questions.

Comment: I'm *always* writing out [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) programs here, and it takes a programmer 2 seconds to remove that line, so I'm not going to stop doing that. Sorry. He won't be able to use the code as-is anyway without removing the Main method.

Comment: Possible make list -> string[]?

Comment: @user3129940 Which list are you talking about?

Comment: One disadvantage, it won't filter out if the badWord item is just part of the input word. badword: read, input: reading. Will still output reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx. E.g. compare with a match list of banned words and replace matches or the first three characters of your match with '*'.
To do so, you can use regular expression options (link includes examples): [Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Set options to "Ignore all whitespaces" and do the match. This way all combinations (e.g. f.u.c.k, f.....u...ck, ... ) [. = space] are caught. You can also ignore case sensitivity this way.

Usage sample taken from MSDN (see link above):

```
string pattern = @"d \w+ \s";
string input = "Dogs are decidedly good pets.";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}// found at index {1}.", match.Value, match.Index);
// The example displays the following output: 
//    'Dogs // found at index 0. 
//    'decidedly // found at index 9
```